# Class toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code that is suppose to be a script that changes the color of the square after you click on in using toggleclass() method in jquery. I think my code is right but I can not get the square to change color. what am I doing wrong? thanks

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        <script>
           $( "p" ).click(function() {
             $( this ).toggleClass( "p.over" );
           });
        </script>
        <style>
            p { background:#DAA520; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; 
                padding:5px;width:20%;}
            p.over { background: #ADFF2F; }
            span { color:red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click or double click here.</p>
        <span></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `toggleClass("over")`

Comment: You want to toggle the class `over` on the clicked `p`. What you are doing now is toggle the class `p.over` on the clicked `p`.

Comment: You also need to either wrap your code in a document ready call or put it at the end of the document. Otherwise it's trying to refer to elements that don't exist yet. Also, what's this line supposed to do: `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">`?

Comment: time to study some tutorials on basic jQuery use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the toggleClass call, you only need the class name, not the selector: `toggleClass('over')` instead of `toggleClass('p.over')`.

Then, you have two opening script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<script>
```

Remove the first one.

Next, you're binding an event listener to an element that's not in the DOM yet at the time the script executes.

Simple fix: move the script to the bottom of the page.

Another way: either execute the script when the DOM is ready (by wrapping it inside a document ready callback: [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)) or use dynamic binding using jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/7g95yvyo/

---

And the last, but not the least, learn to use browser's console - it will help you tremendeously while learning and debugging JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

css `class` is a `.whatever` rule, You don't have any classes in your CSS definitions, just elements.

```
.foo { color: puce } /* this is a class */
p { color: chartreuse } /* this is an element */
p.foo { color: aubergine } /* this is an element AND a class */

toggleClass('foo');
```

You're toggling on `element.class`, but toggleClass expects ONLY a class, not the element.